# Java servlet, reading from file, array out of Bound

Tags: java, string, servlets

I'm making a java servlet, and my task is to get the sum cost of products written in file:

```
category1 1 10 101 1 good1
category6 2 11 105 2 good5
category1 5 13 103 3 good4
category3 6 14 102 4 good2
category5 3 12 107 2 good1
```

The cost is in column 4. I have written:

```
    public int Sum_of_Elements()throws IOException{
    int sum = 0;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Data.txt"));
    String line = "";
    while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
        String[] columns = line.split(" ");
        sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(columns[4]);
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
    return sum;
}
```

And it doesn't work. When i go to servlet page I get

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
```

What's wrong ? and how to fix it ?

Comment: Seems there is some line with fewer columns (probably the last one).

Comment: Have you tried some debugging statements to figure out what's wrong? Try printing the length of `columns` and see what the output is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code will fail if there is e.g. an empty line in the file, or a line formatted differently, or if the spaces are actually tabs (maybe there are more reasons). If you want to program defensively, you should do:

```
while((line=br.readLine())!=null) {
    String[] columns = line.split(" ");
    if( columns != null && columns.length >= 5 ) {
        sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(columns[4]);
    }
    else {
        // do what you must here; it may be an error to encounter such a line:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("malformatted line: " + line);
        // or it may be OK to swallow the exceptional case
        // or you may only need to silently log it:
        logger.warn("malformatted line: " + line);
        // etc...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no index 4 in your columns array. Check your length of columns array. It will be lesser than 5, ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException is thrown when an illegal index of the array is accessed. Check the array length like this

```
  if( columns != null && columns.length >= 5 )
        sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(columns[4]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code as following and it was fine. make sure that your Data file is ASCII

```
import java.io.*;

public class Test{

public static void main(String[] args){
    try{
        int sum = 0;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Data.txt"));
        String line = "";
        while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
            String[] columns = line.split(" ");
            sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(columns[4]);
        }
        System.out.println("Sun:" + sum);


        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("error:" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```